# Vimeo API connection issue : what to do?

Tags: bash, curl, vimeo

I'm following the [API authentification doc](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication) but I don't really know what to do… The main goal is to upload a video through curl. I've tried their python script, but you do not get information regarding your upload, like progress or speed.

So I'm doing that :

```
code=`echo 'myID:mySecret' | base64`
echo `curl --data 'Authorization : basic $code' --data 'grant_type : yes' http://vimeo.com/oauth/authorize/client`
```

But I don't get anything in return :

[image]

Ok so I guess my request have been sent, but then what ? Shouldn't I get a response or something ?

edit : so I had better luck with this :

```
code=`echo -n 'myID:mySecret' | base64`
```

echo `curl -H 'Authorization: basic $code' -d 'grant_type=client_credentials' https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize/client`

But still stuck with this :

```
{ "error": "You must provide a valid authenticated access token." }
```

Answer (score 1):

1 - You shouldn't pass your basic auth header (`Authorization`) as POST data. Change `--data` to `-H`.

2 - The POST data you try to send is ill-formed. GET and POST data are formatted like this : `key=value&key2=value2`.

3 - You don't send this request to the right adress. Vimeo API is located at `http://api.vimeo.com` ; )

Last thing : `echo` returns a `\n` at the end by default. You can use `-n` switch to prevent this behavior.

Comment: Ok so I've modified it that way :

    code=`echo -n 'myID:mySecret' | base64`

    echo `curl -H 'Authorization: basic $code' -d 'grant_type=client_credentials' https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize/client`

But still no luck…

Comment: The client token is not attached to a user, so its not able to upload videos. You must generate an access token on behalf of a user via the authorization code grant listed in the docs, or the "generate token" ui in your app settings